# Will 100% CPU or 100% MEM utilization make linux server more unstable?

Tags: linux

Will 100% CPU or 100% MEM utilization make linux server more unstable? Such that it crashes and in need of reboot.

Because I've heard that:

> "If you cap process at 90% of the CPU, then you are wasting 10% of the computing power for nothing"

vs

> "Please limit the CPU usage under 90% for your process or the system becomes unstable"

Which one of the statement is true?
Shouldn't the linux OS handle high utilization cases?

I understand that on a client machine, I probably don't want 100% CPU usage, as it slows down logins, cli commands and anything interactive. But on a server acting as a **worker node**, should the CPU utilization be 100% or be capped below 100%? Same question for MEM.

Answer (score 3):

A server at 100% CPU usage won't be very responsive to new tasks, and may be sluggish if used interactively, but should continue to work. Worker nodes running CPU intensive tasks at or near 100% is fine. A desktop PC, not so much.

A server at 100% memory will either start killing tasks or will crash.

Comment: Isn't that what swap are for? Or did you assume no swap is allocated?

Comment: My answer assumes no swap. Swap is a mitigation that is often effective.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question with a complex answer.

The short answer is that no, high resource utilization will not by itself make the server unstable or crash. BUT...

The long answer is that it depends. High CPU utilization can, for example, result in poor response times, resource conflicts and compounding issues where requests queue up faster than the server can handle them. This would effectively make the server unstable.

Process priority also plays an important part here. Higher priority tasks are given preference to CPU time which could result in lower priority tasks ending up starved for resources, and thus making the system unstable.

On the other hand, a CPU intensive task that is intentionally set to low priority could utilize any of the otherwise idle CPU without affecting system performance noticeably. Programs such as Folding@Home use this to run in the background without affecting the rest of the system.

High memory utilization can result in swapping, which reduces server performance further and that can effectively make the server unstable.

High memory utilization can also result in Out Of Memory issues which would cause processes to be terminated. That will definitely make the server unstable and prone to crashing.

It all depends on what the server is supposed to do. A webserver at such high utilization would likely risk being unusable, but a video encoding server would do just fine.

And then there's the issues of power draw, heat generation, cooling capacity and so on...

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends on what those servers DO.

Here a story. Windows, but nonetheless the same.

I have a software agent that will use a server to 100% CPU. PERIOD. Regardless how large. It is a statistics simulation agent that takes jobs from a server - ONE PER CORE - and runs them. At low priority, with a higher priority control thread makingsure they are all busy.

100% CPU a problem? NO. This is what it is planned to do.

OTOH a database server with SMART memory management will use as much memory as possible for caching, and release the memory when needed otherwise. Again, not a problem.

Comment: I did specify that the server is used as a "worker node", similar to your simulation agent. My understanding is you're saying in such case, it is not a problem. But you also state "totally depends", so are there counter examples?

Comment: It does "totally depend" and every case is different. If your worker node application is built correctly it shouldn't be any issues as its tasks will run at a lower priority to not affect system stability. However, I've found that in practice many developers lack the experience necessary. This is where you need to do some detective work yourself.

Comment: Sure. Here is a counter example: STUPID developer puts in worker threads with higher priority than the OS (windows: real time priority) and they use up all cycles and necessary work - io etc. including- gets stalled as the drivers never get priority. Yes, seen this happen - and yes, the documentation warns from using this level of thread priority for larger work. Did not stop him. Same with memory - FORCE a db server to use up a LOT mroe memory than physically present, then wonder why the discs are swapping all the time. Seen that one too.